# Apply function for multiple levels of tables/data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, function, numpy

I get a problem in my work. I have tables:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

level1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], [3, 'x', 'x'])),
columns=['name', 'value'])
```

```
   name value
0   a   3
1   b   x
2   c   x
```

I want to sum the `value` column, but it contains “x”s. So I will have to use the second table to calculate “x”s :

```
level2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(['b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'], ['b1', 'b2', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3'], [5, 7, 2, 'x', 9])), 
columns=['name', 'sub', 'value'])
```

```
  name  sub value
0   b   b1  5
1   b   b2  7
2   c   c1  2
3   c   c2  x
4   c   c3  9
```

I should sum the `b1`, `b2` to give “x” for b in `level1` table (x=12). But for c, there is “x”, so a third level table:

```
level3 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(['c', 'c', 'c'], ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'], [2, 4, 9])), 
columns=['name', 'sub', 'value'])
```

```
  name  sub value
0   c   c1  2
1   c   c2  4
2   c   c3  9
```

Now, we can get the sum value for `value` column in `level1` table.

My question is: can we use a function to calculate it easily? If there are more levels, how can we loop them till no “x”?

It is OK to combine `level2` and `level3`.

Comment: what are `b`, `c` and `x` here? are these strings? other variables? please include a valid example (the current sample results in a syntax error).

Comment: @enke they are strings. apologises.

Comment: Did you try to construct your data as DataFrames? they don't have the shape you claim to here. For example, `level_1` doesn't have 2 columns.

Comment: @enke Errr... sorry again. Now ok, edited on phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way using `combine_first` and `replace`:

```
from functools import reduce
l1 = level1.assign(sub=level1['name']+'1').replace('x', np.nan).set_index(['name', 'sub'])
l2 = level2.replace('x', np.nan).set_index(['name', 'sub'])
l3 = level3.replace('x', np.nan).set_index(['name', 'sub'])

reduce(lambda x, y: x.combine_first(y), [l3,l2,l1]).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Output:

```
      value
name       
a       3.0
b      12.0
c      15.0
```

---

### Complete example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

level1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], [3, 'x', 'x'])),
                      columns=['name', 'value'])

level2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(['b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'], 
                               ['b1', 'b2', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3'], 
                               [5, 7, 2, 'x', 9])), 
                      columns=['name', 'sub', 'value'])

level3 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(['c', 'c', 'c'], 
                               ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'], 
                               [2, 4, 9])),
                      columns=['name', 'sub', 'value'])

from functools import reduce
l1 = level1.assign(sub=level1['name']+'1')\
           .replace('x', np.nan)\
           .set_index(['name', 'sub'])
l2 = level2.replace('x', np.nan)\
           .set_index(['name', 'sub'])
l3 = level3.replace('x', np.nan)\
           .set_index(['name', 'sub'])

out = reduce(lambda x, y: x.combine_first(y), 
             [l3,l2,l1]).groupby(level=0).sum()
print(out)
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is a combination of merge(multiple merges actually) and a groupby:

```py
(level2
.merge(level3, on = ['name', 'sub'], how = 'left', suffixes = (None, '_y'))
.assign(value = lambda df: np.where(df.value.eq('x'), df.value_y, df.value))
.groupby('name', as_index = False)
.value
.sum()
.merge(level1, on = 'name', how = 'right', suffixes = ('_x',None))
.assign(value = lambda df: np.where(df.value.eq('x'), df.value_x, df.value))
.loc[:, ['name', 'value']]
)

  name value
0    a     3
1    b  12.0
2    c  15.0
```